# Multiple ArrayAdapters - getView is not called in the last one

Tags: android, listview, getview

I've got two ListViews, treatmentListView and diaryListView. If an item is clicked in treatmentListView i want to display that item's diaryListView. My problem is that getView is not getting called in MyDiaryAdapter and no items are displayed. Anyone got a fix?

```
private void fillListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Treatment> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.treatmentsListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void fillDiaryListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Diary> diaryAdapter = new MyDiaryAdapter();
    listDiary = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.diaryListView);
    listDiary.setAdapter(diaryAdapter);

}


private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Treatment>
{
    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(TreatmentList.this, R.layout.treatment_view, treatments);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.treatment_view, parent, false);
        }
        Treatment currentTreatment = treatments.get(position);
        TextView textMake = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMake);
        textMake.setText(currentTreatment.getName());
        TextView textStarted = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textStarted);
        TextView textMethod = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMethod);
        return itemView;
    }
}

private class MyDiaryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Diary>
{

    public MyDiaryAdapter()
    {
        super(TreatmentList.this, R.layout.diary_view, notes);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.diary_view, parent, false);
        }
        Diary currentNote = notes.get(position);
        TextView textMake = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMake);
        textMake.setText(currentNote.getTitle());
        return itemView;


    }
}
```

EDIT: 
Here "notes" is populated.

```
private void filldiaryList(Treatment treatment)
{
    notes = dbDiary.findDiaryNotes(treatment);
}
```

Heres how the first list's onClick is handled:

```
    private void registerClickCallback() {
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.treatmentsListView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id)
        {
            Treatment clickedTreatment = treatments.get(position);
            loadDiaryList(clickedTreatment);
        }
    });

}
```

EDIT 2:
The whole file:

```
public class TreatmentList extends Activity
{
private ListView list, listDiary;
private List<Treatment> treatments;
private List<Diary> notes;
private DbHandlerTreatments db;
private DbHandlerDiary dbDiary;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    db = new DbHandlerTreatments(this);
    dbDiary = new DbHandlerDiary(this);

    loadTreatmentList();

}

private void registerClickCallback() {
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.treatmentsListView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id)
        {
            Treatment clickedTreatment = treatments.get(position);
            loadDiaryList(clickedTreatment);
        }
    });

}

private void registerDiaryClickCallback() {
    listDiary = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.diaryListView);
    listDiary.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id)
        {
            Diary note = notes.get(position);
            System.out.println(note.getTitle());
        }
    });

}

private void fillTreatmentList()
{
    treatments = db.findAllTreatments();
}

private void filldiaryList(Treatment treatment)
{
    notes = dbDiary.findDiaryNotes(treatment);
}


private void loadTreatmentList()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.treatments);
    fillTreatmentList();
    fillListView();
    registerClickCallback();
}

private void loadDiaryList(Treatment treatment)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.diaries);
    filldiaryList(treatment);
    fillDiaryListView();
    registerDiaryClickCallback();
}

private void fillListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Treatment> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.treatmentsListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void fillDiaryListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Diary> diaryAdapter = new MyDiaryAdapter();
    listDiary = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.diaryListView);
    listDiary.setAdapter(diaryAdapter);

}


private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Treatment>
{
    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(TreatmentList.this, R.layout.treatment_view, treatments);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.treatment_view, parent, false);
        }
        Treatment currentTreatment = treatments.get(position);
        TextView textMake = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMake);
        textMake.setText(currentTreatment.getName());
        TextView textStarted = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textStarted);
        TextView textMethod = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMethod);
        return itemView;
    }
}

private class MyDiaryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Diary>
{

    public MyDiaryAdapter()
    {
        super(TreatmentList.this, R.layout.diary_view, notes);
        listDiary.invalidateViews();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.diary_view, parent, false);
        }

        Diary currentNote = notes.get(position);
        TextView textMake = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMake);
        textMake.setText(currentNote.getTitle());
        return itemView;


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is "notes" populated? And where are you handling the "onItemClickListener" method for the first list? You should add more code relating to this.

Comment: @JML I have updated my question with the information now.

Answer (score 1):

In case, there is no code for onItemClickLister of the treatment and diary. I suggest 2 things.

1. If you use any array, list... in the adapter, in the getCount() function of each array, you should return the size. NOTE: make sure you call `datasetchange`
2. Listview has one thing, it recycles view. in MyListAdapter, you check the convertView with null but no else brace. `TextView textMake = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMake);` this may make no sense.

Comment: thanks for reply. It doesnt however get into MyDiaryAdapter's getView at all. It does load  R.layout.diary_view, but it doesnt get the itemview.

Comment: and what do you mean with "make sure you call "datasetchange" ? @kidnan1991

Comment: Point 2) isn't true, he's always retrieving the views of the row via findViewById (and the view is always not-null). So in that case he doesn't need any esle brace. But in the future, he should check for the commonly used "holder pattern" to cache all those views instead of having to search them.

Comment: 1. @themanwithballs: As i know, here  you want to "add" an item in the listview (showing the label). So, you have to add this by using your adapter, example `diaryAdapter.add("new item");`, and you should call `diaryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` 
 2. @JML: Thank you for pointing me out. But I see that the problem may be when the convertView is not null, and this convertview is not actually the view that we need, and that we do nothing. So I suggest him to remove the check null (and this means inflating view every times ).
anyway, view holder is a good selection;

Answer (score 0):

Try calling notifyDataSetChanged() on diaryAdapter after loading the diary list

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id)
 {
     Treatment clickedTreatment = treatments.get(position);
     loadDiaryList(clickedTreatment);
     diaryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```

Note that you'll need to make diaryAdapter a class instance variable instead of a local variable of the fillDiaryListView method

Edit: to complete a bit my answer, the notifyDataSetChanged (although the name may be self explanatory) tells the adapter that the data model that "fills" the list has changed, forcing the adapter to start all the process of calling the callbacks again (an now your array should be not empty)